# Squarespace spacing between sections

Tags: html, css, http, squarespace

I have a slideshow section and a text box section. I want to minimize the spacing between them such that the text box is directly under the slideshow photo previews. Basically I want to get rid of the space in yellow. I know I need to paste in some CSS but the stuff I'm finding online isn't reducing the spacing enough.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page containing the blocks in question?

Comment: https://www.theadvisoregroup.com/transactions

Comment: thank you in advance if you can help in the slightest!

Answer (score 0):

First, try adjusting the section's height. See the "Change section styles" [here](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/360027987711-Page-sections-in-version-7-1).

> In the Format tab, you can change these details:
>
> Section Height - The height of the section. Sections with more content
> may display at a taller height than your setting. This also affects
> the amount of padding above and below your section's content.

If that doesn't work, you can force the bottom padding by adding CSS to the CSS Editor. You'd need to write the CSS to accommodate all widths, including mobile, but it would be something like this:

```
[data-section-id="5fb9813532611c2ac198eff9"] {
  padding-bottom: 35px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. now it appear that I need to reduce the padding around the block text so it pushes to the top of the section. Do you know what code to use here?

Comment: I added a new picture with code and the chrome add-in for section ID's to explain!

Comment: Unfortunately, someone deleted your comment containing your password, probably because they do not understand that it is a view-only password, not a security concern. In any case, I can no longer access your site without the view-only password.